# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se muestren solo los datos de la semana actual?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, vb.net

Tengo una tabla en la que hay un campo tipo fecha, que representa la fecha en que se guarda el registro. Me gustaría recuperar los registros guardados durante la semana actual

He intentado con la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM [encuestainf] WHERE YEARWEEK(Fecha)=YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) ;
```

pero me da error con el mensaje '`YEARWEEK' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por que en SQL Server no existe la función `YEARWEEK` en su lugar puedes usar [`DATEPART()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), tampoco existe `CURDATE()` que en realidad es `GETDATE()`

```
SELECT * 
       FROM [encuestainf] 
       WHERE DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,Fecha) = DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GETDATE())
             AND DATEPART(YEAR, Fecha) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE());
```

Ten en cuenta que `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,Fecha)`, te da un numero de semana en el año, 
pero sin importar el año, por lo que hay que asegurarse que el año también sea el mismo: `AND DATEPART(YEAR, Fecha) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE());`